# How do I configure a class objects methods from a function within the class?

Tags: python

I have an class instance containing certain attributes with default values. I would like to be able to change the values of these class methods later on by comparing them to a library of keys and values, and changing the class variables to the corresponding library values if they exist.

Ideally, I would like to be able to make a function WITHIN the object that takes a library as an argument and changes the values accordingly. But I get the feeling that's not possible.

Is it possible? If so, how? And if it is not possible, how can I make a separate function that takes in an object and a library, and configures the objects attributes to the libraries attributes.
(note, I do not want to add or remove any attributes, just change the value).

```
class assignment(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id


    def configureAssignment(self, configFile):

        with open(configFile, "r") as inputfile:
            config = json.loads(inputfile.read())
            print("config is:", config)


        for key in config:
            try:
                self.key = key
            except:
                log("error, non-existent variable defined")
```

Comment: What is meant by `library of keys and values`? Please provide some concrete examples.

Comment: Something along the lines of:
config = {'id' : '235235' , 'name' : 'test'}
In this case I'd like to check whether my object has an attribute "id", or "name", and in that case, change the values of those attributes to "235235" and "name"  respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `hasattr()` to check whether your class has the requisite variable before trying to set it:

```
if hasattr(self, key):
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

---

But honestly, a safer way to handle this problem would be to initialize the class with, say, a `dict` of keys and values, and have your function (and other facets of your program) manipulate *that* instead of manipulating the class attributes themselves.